# (Fluent)NHibernate: Mapping an IDictionary<MappedClass, MyEnum>

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, mapping, one-to-many

I've found a number of posts about this but none seem to help me directly. Also there seems to be confusion about solutions working or not working during different stages of FluentNHibernate's development.

I have the following classes:

```
public class MappedClass
{
    ...
}

public enum MyEnum
{
    One,
    Two
}

public class Foo
{
    ...
    public virtual IDictionary<MappedClass, MyEnum> Values { get; set; }
}
```

My questions are:

1. Will I need a separate (third) table of MyEnum?
2. How can I map the MyEnum type? Should I?
3. What should Foo's mapping look like?

I've tried mapping HasMany(x => x.Values).AsMap("MappedClass")...
This results in: NHibernate.MappingException : Association references unmapped class: MyEnum

Comment: You're using an entity as the key and an enum as the value?

Comment: are there specific considerations or advantages to the alternative?

Comment: specifically, every Foo may have one MyEnum value per MappedClass. i'm not clear on what the best way to represent this structure would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this questions is a duplicate of [Fluent code for mapping an IDictionary<SomeEntity, int>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360976/). The solution was to use hbm.xml to map a ternary association table. It looks like at the time FluentNHibernate's AsTernaryAssocation() method only worked for entity types. I can't tell if this has changed, or if it is a planned feature.